# How to Detect Collision Between Entity and Viewport

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, crafty

I am using [Crafty.js](http://craftyjs.com). I want the player to die when they hit the side of the viewport (they need to keep moving to stay alive). How do I detect a collision between the player entity and the side/edge of the viewport? I have looked at [Crafty.viewport](http://craftyjs.com/api/Crafty-viewport.html), but have not been able to find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your entity's 2D method [within](http://craftyjs.com/api/2D.html#-within) combined with your viewport's property [bounds](http://craftyjs.com/api/Crafty-viewport.html#Crafty-viewport-bounds) as input argument. It will check if your player's rectangle is within the viewport.